# renaming file names with consecutive number in UNIX

Tags: file, unix, rename

I have file names with prefix - "file" and random number suffix. for example:

```
file2344, file1244, file123, file12345, file0012
```

I want to create the files renamed with sequential number so that they can work well in arrays. for example:

```
file1, file2, file3, file4, file5
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that:

```
i=1
for f in file*; do
    mv "$f" file$i
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: +1 You could do `(( i++ ))` instead of `i=$((i+1))`, assuming you have bash/ksh and depending on the version.  Also, you need to quote `"$f"` during your `mv` command in case a file has spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script:

[numerate.sh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numerate/files/numerate.sh/download)

This should work for you:

```
./numerate.sh -d <your image folder> -b <start number> -p image_ -s .jpg -o numerically -r
```